# VMWare.Vim load session: how long is this valid?

Tags: .net, vmware

I'm reading up on some examples here: https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/windowstoolkit/wintk40/doc/viwin_devg.pdf

The description I'm referring to is on page 14-15.

It describes saving and loading sessions for enhanced security.  I'm assuming these session are fairly transient, much like the usual web sessions (PHP, .Net, etc).

Is that the case?

If they are fairly transient, how is this meant to be used?

Comment: Provide example of what you have tried.

Comment: I don't believe the context of my question requires such.  If you know of relevant documentation I need to be reading feel free to link it.